# Creating and sending file without saving to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so I am trying to make a file, and send it as a response via expressjs. I've tried the following:

```
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';
const writeStream = createWriteStream('./file.sxcu');
const data = {
  "test": "value"
}
writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

However, that saves to the disk which I don't want.

Comment: If you dont want to save to disk, store the data in buffer.

Comment: Do you want to create a file or just send some binary content in a response?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to send a file that the user automatically downloads.

Comment: @kg99 I'm trying to do that, but don't really know how to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Express response.json() function to send your data as a file to clients, like the following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, response ) {
    const fileName = 'file.sxcu';
    const data = {
        "test": "value"
    }
    response.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
    response.json(data);
})
```

Comment: Hey, this works but the '' that is wraps ${fileName} has to be removed since it's actually downloaded as the name!